# How is the best way to integrate using loops

Tags: integration, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I'm using Mathematica, and I want to integrate a function f[wr] in wr using some method that works with a Table/Do/For in the variable wr.

I tried to use something like the Riemann's sum, to evaluate the function in some point wr_0 times the spacing (in this case 0.01). The problem is that wr depends on "[Micro]" and for each value of Micro, the integral in wr would change its limits (from  [Micro] - 50*kt to [Micro] + 50*kt).

```
kb = 8.61*10^-5;
Te = 300;
kt = kb*Te;
sum = 0;
sum1 = 0;
data = Table[
   {
    Table[
     {
      sum = sum + (f[wr]*0.01);
      sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr]*(wr - \[Micro])*0.01);

      }
     , {wr, \[Micro] - 50*kt, \[Micro] + 50*kt, 0.01}];

    \[Micro], sum1/(Te*sum)
    }

   , {\[Micro], -0.4, 0.4, 0.1}];
```

I think this code, is not doing what I want. That is, for each value of Micro, calculate the integral (sum1 and sum) for a range of wr's and store, then for other value of Micro, do it all again, at the end i want the output of the quotient of these integrals. How could I implement that?